# Why Python3's builtin library doesn't use type hints?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.6, type-hinting

The type hints have been proposed for more than 2 years: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/

Though the proposal is accepted now. It seems that even Python's built-in core library doesn't utilize this feature/syntax at all.

Does anyone have ideas about why Python3's builtin library doesn't convert to type hints? It is supposed to make the code more robust, right? So why not use it?

Or is there any plan to migrate current code of core library to the one with type hint?

Comment: This is a question for the Python mailing list, not SO.

Comment: It'd be a lot of code to add everywhere for no immediate benefit.

Comment: If I has guess I'd say its because converting the entire Python standard library to type hints would be a massive undertaking. And honestly, while type hints _do_ help with Python code's readability, there not necessary. Perfectly robust Python code can be created just fine without using type hints.

Comment: Adding type hints does not magically or immediately make code more robust. A strong argument can be made that declaring types helps improve code clarity, even in a dynamically / duck typed language. But that's a long-term prospect and process, not something that can be done immediately, or that yields immediate benefit.

Comment: Type hints only help tools that do static analysis of the code. But those tools already know about the standard library because the tool writers did it the hard way. So it's a lot of work to achieve something that has already been done differently.